# JUnit test case runs multiple times in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, test-suite

I have Test classes and covering test suite in the same package. When I right click on package and use "run with junit", eclipse runs my test classes independently and also from my test suite. So basically double execution. Is there any way to prevent it?

Note: Under jenkins it is fine as I use surefire and created individual test classes name such that it does not get included by surefire default naming convention.

Comment: You could change the Run Configuration for that test to just run a single test (your test suite).  (Alternately, you could move your test suite into a different package)

Comment: moving test cases to subpackage works. But if I run test at the project level (right click on project and run test cases) it still runs both of them.  Changing configuration will work on individual eclipse instance but not for the whole team.

Comment: Oh!  You want to share Run Configurations!  Hang on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share Eclipse Run Configurations with a team of programmers...

- Open the Run Configuration for the desired Test Suite
- Switch to the "Common" tab.
- Select [x] Shared file, and browse for the folder you want to place the launcher files in (the project root directory is fine, or perhaps create a "launchers" subdirectory)

If you name the run configuration "MyProject - Test Suite", this will create a file in the selected folder called "`MyProject - Test Suite.launch`", which you can add to your version control and share with the team.

Configure to run only the desired test ... your test suite.

After your team members pull the "`*.launch`" files into their workspace, the Run Configuration will appear in their "Run -> Run Configurations ..." dialog.  Once they use it once, it should appear on the Run button drop down menu.  Alternately, you can check an option in the "Display in favourites menu" of the "Common" tab, if you want the Run Configuration to be a favourite for all team members.